# Mongoose - Optimal way to implement friendships: 2 pointers, pushing once to both arrays?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, nosql

Question: When creating something like a simple many to many friendship in mongoose, I know how to create it on ONE object, for instance, the code below in the controller shows that I am finding one user, and pushing to his friends array another user, being referenced via ObjectId.

In this way, when I look at the Json file, I can see user with _id of "57ed2e8c9cf3083c2ccec173", has a new friend in his friend's array, and I can run a population to get that friend user document. However, user who was added as a friend does not have these capabilities because his array of friends is still empty.

I know there are multiple ways to go about this, as I have read the docs, which say I could simply now push user 1 into user 2's friends array, but, in the words of the docs: "It is debatable that we really want two sets of pointers as they may get out of sync. Instead we could skip populating and directly find() the stories we are interested in."

In other words, if you have an event model with many users, and user model with many events, and you need to access the array of users from the event document, and the array of events from the user document... Would it be best to just push each instance into each other?

Is this the correct way of thinking?

Thanks

```

```
app.post('/friendships', function(req, res) {
  User.findOne({
    _id: "57ed2e8c9cf3083c2ccec173"
  }, function(err, user1) {
    User.findOneAndUpdate({
      _id: "57ed2ebbedcd96a4536467f7"
    }, {$push: {friends: user1 }}, {upsert: true}, function(err, user2) {
      console.log("success");
    })
  })
});
```

```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is the correct way of thinking, considering the limitations of Mongo for that sort of data.

When you store such an information in two places, you need to make sure that it is consistent - i.e. either it is present in both places or not. You don't have transactions in Mongo so the only way you can do it is to chain the requests and manually roll back the first one if the second one failed, hoping that it's possible to do (which may not be the case - if the second update failed because you lost a connection to the database, there is a good chance that your rollback will fail as well, in which case your database is left in an inconsistent state).

An alternative would be to store only one half of the relationship - e.g. only store events in users, but no users in events, using your example. That way the data would be consistently stored in one place but then if you wanted to get a list of users for a certain event, you'd have to make a possibly expensive database lookup instead of having it already present in the event document.

In practice in most cases I have seen storing data in two places and trying to keep them consistent.

Though it is usually done with storing documents IDs, so instead of:

```
{$push: {friends: user1}}
```

it's usually:

```
{$push: {friends: user1._id}}
```

(or just using the `_id` if you have it in the first place)

And instead of `$push` you can use `$addToSet` - see: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/addToSet/

Here is a basic concept of adding a two-directional friendship between `id1` and `id2`:

```
function addFriendship(id1, id2) {
  User.findOneAndUpdate({_id: id1}, {$addToSet: {friends: id2}}, err => {
    if (err) {
      // failure - no friendship added
    } else {
      // first friendship added, trying the second:
      User.findOneAndUpdate({_id: id2}, {$addToSet: {friends: id1}}, err => {
        if (err) {
          // second friendship not added - rollback the first:
          User.findOneAndUpdate({_id: id1}, {$pull: {friends: id2}}, err => {
            if (err) {
              // we're screwed
            } else {
              // rolled back - consistent state, no friendship
            }
          });
        } else {
          // success - both friendships added
        }
      });
    }
  });
}
```

Not pretty and not bulletproof but that's the most you can hope for with a database with no transactions where denormalized data is the norm.

(Of course friendship don't always work that way that they have to be bidirectional, but this is just an example of a pattern that is common for any many-to-many relationaship.)

Comment: Thank you for the great example. The reason I am using {friends: friend} instead of friend.id is because my model looks like this: var UserSchema = new Schema({
  name: String,
  friends: [{ friend: {type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: "User"}, status: { type: String, default: "pending"} }]
}).

As you can see, I not only need to retrieve the ID of the friend, but also the friendship status. This seems to be working thus far, now I need to just teach myself the rollback technique you have just mentioned. Does this make sense? Thanks.

Comment: And also...lol'd at "we're screwed". It's true. If the database connection breaks after the very first "else", even for 1 second, then even the rollback won't help, because it won't be able to run the rollback if the database connection is off. But the chance of the database connection breaking the EXACT moment someone hits that Friend Request button is extremely slim, no?

Comment: @Tyler Yeah, it makes sense if you have friendships with status. As for the chances of the database connection breaking at the exact moment someone hits that Friend Request button is extremely slim, which is to say that it will only start to be a problem when your system gets really popular. That's the problem with unlikely events - they never happen and then they do, or they happen all the time on busy systems, or almost never. I have no idea, it may never happen, but you never know - maybe it's a good idea to send you an email when it does happen so that you could investigate the issue.

Comment: @Tyler If you think this answers your question then you can consider [accepting the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) so that this question shows up as having an accepted answer in searches.